# Login Failed: SqlException was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I try to create a login page. I am getting the following error. I searched for solution on Google, but none of them helped me.

> Cannot open database "WebApp" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'username'.

My code -

```
  protected void loginbtn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from UserProfile where UserName =@UserName and Password=@Password", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txtUserName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPWD.Text);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Invalid Username and Password')</script>");
        }


    }
```

Web Config code:

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="dbconnection" connectionString="Data Source=GLN027\SQL2008R2EXPRESS;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=WebApp; User ID=sa;Password=admin@123"/></connectionStrings>
```

Unable to find my mistake.Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the password you are passing in connectuion string is correct?

Comment: How does the exception in the title relate to this? And please don't store passwords without hashing them.

Comment: Try making integrated security as false

Comment: And do you really have a user called "username" in your SQL Server?

Comment: The connection string has a user name and password yet it is telling SQL Server to use integrated security. So the user name and password in the connection string will be ignored, the windows user id that the application is running under will be used to connect to the database.

Comment: Your `User ID=sa;Password=admin@123` is wrong. Please check that before use.

Comment: @JeffSiver Thanks now am able to login by replacing true by false in  integrated security.

Comment: if Integrated Security = true then no need of Username and Password .. set it false if you want to use Username and Password for SQL - SERVER

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should have "Integrated Security = true" if the user account which runs the application has access to database.

I see that you are using SQL authentication by providing specific userId and password. If you really want SQL authentication, mark Integrated Security as false.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: its already answered in comment what is special in your answer ?